# How can you detect ClickOnce in IE10?

Tags: clickonce, internet-explorer-10

We've got a ClickOnce application that we launch from our site. We can detect if the browser supports ClickOnce in Firefox, Chrome, and all versions of IE except for IE10 in metro mode.

I believe that IE10 in metro mode will launch the ClickOnce app if the .Net Framework is installed (which it should be), but we have no way to detect that it will launch successfully. We want to be able to provide a page with instructions if ClickOnce is not supported (for example, we provide a link to the plugin for Firefox and Chrome).

I saw a question on determining if [IE10 is in metro mode or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236867/differentiating-between-ie10-desktop-and-metro), but I need to know if ClickOnce is supported.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is running Windows 8 Pro, they should be able to install a ClickOnce with either the "Metro" IE10 or the desktop IE10 (I just tried it on mine).

If the user is running WindowsRT, the user can not install a ClickOnce application using either browser.

So can't you just check the OS?

Comment: I know that it will run in IE10 metro mode if they have the correct .Net version. The problem is that it doesn't include the .Net versions in the useragent string so we can't know if they have the right version of .Net installed. This allows us to provide detailed instructions for our users (many aren't very computer literate).

Comment: Are you not having your customers use the bootstrapper (setup.exe)? It will check and install it if needed, or not, and then continue with the C/O app. Are you trying to link directly to the deployment manifest (.application file) to install the C/O app?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't. We need the querystring parameters. When running through setup.exe, the application doesn't get them (at least it didn't 5 years ago, when we created the application :)

Comment: It still doesn't get the query string parameters. I know they removed the .NET version from the user action string, which is very vexing. It also broke their own publish.htm page, but I don't think they've realized this yet. Grrrrr.