# Forcing IE10 in UI/Metro to switch to desktop mode

Tags: windows, user-interface, microsoft-metro, desktop, internet-explorer-10

Is there a way, using HTML code that a website would detect a user using IE10 in UI/Metro mode and either offer a button to or force open IE10 in desktop mode?

Comment: Have you tried to search for a solution? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a meta element to the head of your page to tell IE to add a dialog bar, prompting the user to switch to the desktop version of IE10:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true" />
```

You can also configure your web server to do the same using a HTTP header:

```
X-UA-Compatible: requiresActiveX=true
```

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/31/web-sites-and-a-plug-in-free-web.aspx for details.