# Customizing The Site xxxx.com uses add-ons that requires IE on Desktop message

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

We have portal which requires plugin to be downloaded. When we try to open it in Windows 8 metro mode it gives the message to switch to desktop mode since metro mode does not allow add ins.It shows the message as below.

**The Site xxxx.com uses add-ons that requires IE on Desktop. It show three button**

1. Open
2. Don't Show again for this site
3. Close

When we click "open" it will switch to desktop mode.**Normally Users has tendency not to click on open button** and webpage stops there it self.

I come to following conclusion that if we can achieve any of the two below option we can solve mode issue in windows 8.

1. Show big pop up message that will ask user to switch to desktop mode or cancel operation.Windows doesn't provide any API to detect the Metro mode.Is there any way to do this.
2. Can we customize the message to look more bigger and understandable to most of the user.

**Note:** I tried using screen size vs windows size it is working but I dont know its long term solution or not

Comment: What's this got to do with c++??

Comment: Can you give an example of a site that shows the message?

Comment: @FrederikH http://myharmony.com/

Comment: @aleguna sorry...you are correct

Answer (score 0):

You should check for ActiveX support. Look at this answer for examples: [Detect Metro UI Version of IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751479/javascript-detect-metro-ui-version-of-ie-10)

You should also read the recommendation from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801221(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have tried that sample that wont work if active X is filtered on Desktop IE 10