# Detect metro mode in windows 8 / 8.1 using javascript / jQuery

Tags: browser, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

Is there any way to detect if browser is running in Windows 8/8.1 (metro) mode or in Desktop mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Detect Metro UI Version of IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751479/javascript-detect-metro-ui-version-of-ie)