# How do I detect if machine is in "tablet mode" in chrome browser running on windows using javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, tablet

I need a chrome extension I am working on to be able to detect when a windows machine is in Tablet Mode because there are certain things regarding window manipulation that cannot be done in this mode.

I've found this answer: [Can you detect "Tablet Mode" in Edge and IE11 using JavaScript on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493093/can-you-detect-tablet-mode-in-edge-and-ie11-using-javascript-on-windows-10/32601200#32601200)
That describes how to do it in the Edge and IE11 browsers, but the same method does not work in chrome.